"UAMP not working right now" after logging in AAOS
I was developing an app in AAOS. i used the sample app as mentioned in documentation.
But in the sample app itself there is an issue.
After login, app displays "UAMP isnt working right now".
I need to implement the same feature in my app without the issue.
I have installed Spotify app from playstore of the AAOS. (you can do this in any emulator which supports google service from preinstalled emulators).
Somehow they have implemented this very smoothly.
Reproduction steps:
switch to media3 branch from Repository link
build and launch app
click on login button
enter username and password in respective screens and click next
After this screen just displays "UAMP isnt working right now"
i have opened an issue regarding this as well in the repository
Github Issue
Expected behaviour: after logging in successfully, app must show list of media as does in Spotify app
i have tried restarting the MediaLibraryService. This works but takes time before displaying the media list and does not seem to be the right way.

Unfortunately, I don't see how your question can be answered here in SO, as it is about debugging code you didn't write nor even read. You filled up an issue in Github so you did what an end-user should do, let's pray the App's devs can help you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
